# Selenium IE protected mode settings are not the same for all zones. The zones in my IE are all disabled

Tags: python-2.7, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to set the security protected mode the same for all zones in IE9, Windows Server 2008 on our server.
But when i click on the Security tab the enabled protected mode checkbox is disabled for all the zones.
I am a member of the Administrator group on the server.

How can i enable the checkbox so i can set the zones the same level for each zone?

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to enable the Protected Mode check box.

1) Close all Internet Explorer and Windows Explorer windows that are currently open.

2) Reopen Internet Explorer.

3) Click the Tools button, and then click Internet options.

4) Click the Advanced tab, and then click Reset. ...

5) In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, click Reset.

6) Reopen Internet Explorer.

7) The Protected Mode check box is now enabled.  You can change the zone levels.